# Powershell prompt at bottom

Tags: powershell, cmd

I'd like to get my prompt in powershell to be at the bottom instead of "from top to bottom".

There is a workaround for cmd (https://superuser.com/questions/644326/start-conemu-with-prompt-at-the-bottom) but I can't find a way to make it work in powershell.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you want, but this works fairly well for me.  Save this as a .ps1 file somewhere that makes sense or convert it into a cmdlet if you like.  Then stick it in your profile so it runs when you open a powershell session:

```
cls
$Ui = (Get-Host).UI.RawUI
$Height = $UI.WindowSize.Height
$Coordinates = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates 0,($Height - 1)
$Ui.CursorPosition = $Coordinates
```

Create an alias for it.

```
 New-Alias -Name cl -Value \\Path_to_the_script_or_the_cmdlet
```

Use the alias to clear your screen rather than clear or cls.

Comment: Thats what I was looking for. Thanks! I did put in in prompt :)

Answer (score 3):

Thought, more "clean" version of prompt function. No need of `New-Object ...` Just add/modify your `prompt` in the `$profile`.

```
function prompt {
  # put cursor at the bottom of the buffer
  $rawUI = (Get-Host).UI.RawUI
  $cp = $rawUI.CursorPosition
  $cp.Y = $rawUI.BufferSize.Height - 1
  $rawUI.CursorPosition = $cp

  # and the prompt itself
  Write-Host -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Cyan "PS "
  Write-Host -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow $(get-location).ProviderPath
  return ">"
}
```

Comment: I do like the prompt function you've used. Didn't realize you could do that and I agree that it's less convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

Above methods are fine but they kill your custom prompt like Starship or Ohmyposh so I made this.

```
$DefaultPrompt = $function:prompt
function prompt {
    $DefaultPrompt.Invoke()
    $host.ui.rawui.WindowTitle = $pwd.path

    $host.ui.rawui.CursorPosition = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates 0, ($host.ui.rawui.WindowSize.Height - 1)
}
```

just paste this into your $profile.